# How does the C++ standard accommodate linking to platform dependent components?

Tags: c++, linker, cross-platform, standards

When writing a program, I aim to avoid any unspecified or implementation-defined behaviour. When linking to C++ libraries, I expect them to have been written in a similar way. If I link to a library that used implementation-defined behaviour when it was compiled, does that instantly make my own program implementation-defined according to the standard?

Does it even matter at this point? If the library has already been compiled to object code, I'm not even dealing with implementation-defined C++ - in fact, it may not have even been written in C++. How about when I use an API that is by its nature platform dependent, such as POSIX?

The way that the standard is written seems to assume my "C++ program" is entirely written by me and involves no other pre-compiled components. How does it accommodate the linking of these components and at what points does the standard stop caring about what my program does?

Comment: I'm having a hard time figuring out what your question is. The only real question in here seems to be "Does linking against a library whose source has implementation-defined behavior cause my program to have implementation-defined behavior?", and the answer there is "no".

Comment: @KevinBallard I was having a hard time figuring it out too. What exactly is the extent that the standard covers my program and how does it accommodate linking to components that may provide my program with platform dependent data? My brain is in a muddle.

Comment: The standard covers your program in essentially two areas: the language itself (chapters 1-16 of the spec) and the standard library formal definition and its *defined* formal behaviors (chapter 17+). Throughout that anything that is implementation-defined is noted as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call a function that has unspecified (or implementation-defined, or undefined) behavior, then your program has unspecified (or implementation-defined, or undefined) behavior.

The standard does not define what it means for a program "to be implementation-defined", so I can't answer that part other than to say no, your program is not implementation-defined according to the standard. Its behavior is.

If you use call a function from Posix, then your program depends on (that part of) Posix. The behavior of such a program isn't defined by the C++ standard alone, because the C++ standard doesn't know or care what the Posix function does. However, *given* knowledge of what the Posix function does, you can use the C++ standard to work out what the whole program does. So behavior can be defined by the C++ standard, except for the part that's outside the scope of the C++ standard.

There are also certain situations where you can make your program have undefined behavior simply by linking to a library, without calling the code in it. Violating the One Definition Rule is the obvious example. So far as the standard is concerned, you're entitled to define a function called `pthread_create`, but if you link that program against pthreads, you have undefined behavior.

There is something of a grey area, whether Posix and other OS functions are "part of the program" or "part of the implementation". Take for example `strdup`, which you could easily implement for yourself in a non-Posix environment. If it's "part of the implementation" then of course its behavior is implementation-defined. If it's "part of the program" then the behavior of the program is, well, dependent on the program, in common with the behavior of every C++ program! The C++ standard doesn't really care which way you choose to think of it.

The standard doesn't assume anything about how many authors a program has. Provided that the components you use are documented, it's your responsibility as the person who puts the final program together, to work out whether or not you have used them in a way that makes your program's behavior as defined as you'd like it to be. If they're not documented, or they don't behave as their documentation says they should, then you might like to present a case to their authors that *they* have a responsibility to do something about that ;-)

Comment: This great answer has helped unravel my mind quite a bit. The standard will only cover my ass as far as using the language within my program and using the standard library, but when it comes to linking to other libaries and components, it is my job to make sure that they are all well-defined for the platforms I'm supporting.

Comment: "it is my job to make sure that they are all well-defined" - Note that "well defined" could include "implementation defined". If the author of the library knew the implementation, and the library is not intended to be used on other platforms.

Answer (score 0):

If that library is part of the standard library, you can assume that it's available on any standard conforming platform, and it's behaviour will be as specified, with respect to it's interface.

If not, you can't. And you can't assume that it can be compiled from source for that platform, or ported any other way. And then, you can't port your program to that platform by just recompiling. Which is the purpose of writing programs without implementation defined behaviour.